# How to sort Nulls Last with Elastic?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sorting, elasticsearch

How I can sort String field in elastic search. I need to take it last, but cannot do that.

I try some sorting by ASC but it is not working

**Example:**

```
[
{"url":"https://amazon"},
{"url":"https://amazon"},
{"url":null},
{"url":"https://amazon"}
]
```

**my code:**

```
sourceBuilder = sourceBuilder.sort("url", SortOrder.ASC)
```

And using my code i get the same

```
I expect to see:
[
{"url":"https://amazon"},
{"url":"https://amazon"},
{"url":"https://amazon"},
{"url":null}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

try  "missing": "_last" in sort

```
GET testindex/_search
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "url": {
        "order": "asc",
        "missing": "_last"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Mapping

```
PUT testindex3/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "url": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please add mapping

Comment: `"url": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        `

Comment: With mapping added in answer I am getting null values in end. I hope null value is not entered as text. ex. I am entering null  url as POST testindex3/_doc
{
  "url": null
} which will treat it as missing value. if entered as "url" :"null" , it will be treated as normal string value in which case custom script sort will be needed to place it last or documents needs to be reindexed with "url" inserted as null

Comment: null valueis entered as null, not is text

Comment: if sorting not as keyword getting error:`"reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [url] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."`

Comment: For sorting on textfield keyword has to be used which uses entire text as keyword. For Null value  not appearing in last, I am unable to find reason.

Comment: Can you paste your actual result (entire hits portion)